# Yet another characterization of weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Suppose $X$ is a locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$. How can I prove that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ weakly converges to $0$ iff $0$ lies in the closed convex hull of any subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$?

The sufficiency follows from [Mazur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma). Can someone give me a hint to prove necessity?

Comment: Necessity is an easy consequence of Hahn Banach Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I still don't get it. Could you give more details?

Comment: If $0$ does not lie in the closed convex hull of $(x_{n_k})$ we can separate $0$ from the closed convex hull by  a continuous linear functional.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I need to prove the opposite implication. Suppose 0 lies in the closed convex hull of any subsequence. How do I show that the sequence weakly converges to 0?

Comment: Is your scalar field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: The complex field

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, see above